# change color of anchor tag on click using CSS

Tags: html, css, computer-science

I have an anchor tag Home this displays homepage and another one Books this display books page. Now when I click on Home link I want it to change it's color and keep the same color until I click on the other link. Similarly, when I click on Books link I want it to change this color and keep the same color until I click other link.

I can do it using JavaScript but I want to know how I can achieve it using CSS only?

I tried with a:active but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Literata:opsz,wght@7..72,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Bookstore</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that, Use `focus`, But if using only that the styling will be lost once another element gains focus, So add a class to your `a` like in my example  `link` then use it in CSS like the demo below:

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

a:focus {
  color: red;
}

:link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Literata:opsz,wght@7..72,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Bookstore</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link">Books</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML code
<a tabindex="1">Your Button</a>


CSS code
a {   
    color: black;  
    font-size: 30px; 
}

a:active {
    color: rebeccapurple;
}

a[tabindex]:focus {
    color:rebeccapurple;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the color as rebeccapurple. I want it to keep it as rebeccapurple until i click on the other link.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a tabindex to each anchor element allows you to apply a :focus pseudo-class:

```css
<style>
ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
ul li a:focus {
  color: red;
}
ul li a:selected {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a tabindex="1" href="#" class="selected"> item1 </a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="1" href="#" class="selected"> item2 </a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="1" href="#" class="selected"> item3 </a></li>
</ul
```